# Shiny observeEvent - how to achieve side effects if code is in a helper function?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I modularize some some of the reactive components in helper files/functions. These are called from within the shiny server function.

This means some of the reactiveValues in scope of the server won't be in scope for the helper function. Since R's function calls use call by value semantics, what's the "right" way for an observeEvent() in a helper function to do the mutation. I could probably fudge things with <<- but that breaks the decoupled compositional organization I'm trying to achieve by having functions/files in the first place.

Comment: Is it possible that you explain more? I have a modulated application with observeEvent(). Probably if you extend your question, I could help you.

Comment: if your observeEvent is factored out into a separate function for which the reactiveValue is out of scope, how do you mutate reactiveValue, since you can't pass by reference in R?

Comment: Ok, tell if I understand that you want to do. You want a function with an observeEvent and inside this observeEvent you want a reactive value. Am I wrong?